# datatables smartsearch v no smart search v regex

Tags: datatables

Given this [datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html) example with the option of regex, smartserach or none of the the two(regex, smartserach) what does smart search do?

For instance under column Name:
typing `Ai` in the search returns 4 entries with or without smart search ticked. **Can anyone provide an example where I can see the difference in smart search ticked or not?**

For instance under column Name:
typing `^[A]` will return 3 entries with regex ticked. ticking smart search or not does not seem to make a difference in this example. **Again, can anyone provide an example where I can see the difference in smart search ticked or not with regex ticked?**

---

### EDIT1

this [link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search) is the documentation that might help

from [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().search()) suggests it might not be good to have smart search and regex enabled: `Note that to perform a smart search, DataTables uses regular expressions, so if enable regular expressions using the second parameter to this method, you will likely want to disable smart searching as the two regular expressions might otherwise conflict and cause unexpected results.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`search.smart`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.smart) option for more details.

> DataTables' built-in filtering is "smart" in that it breaks the user's input into individual words and then matches those words in any position and in any order in the table (rather than simple doing a simple string compare).

In [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html) typing `Junior Author` in Position column will find `Junior Technical Author` position when "smart" mode enabled. With "smart" mode disabled nothing will be found.